# Reminders in Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

Reminders in my app, [Muslim Prayers](http://bit.ly/mpforwp8) works great on Windows Phone 8 and whenever a user taps on any reminder, it simply launches the app.

I have updated my phone to Windows Phone 8.1 and the same app works fine.

However, after re-targeting my app to Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1; the reminders do not launch an app upon tapping on it.

I want to know is this a known bug or am I missing something?

Thanks